# assigning a variable to a very big array make it undefined

Tags: javascript, json, bigdata

I used some endpoint to get simple info for all crypto coins , this list is very big

2 clear examples to illustrate the problem

```
// example one

var arrWithSmallLength = [  {
    name: 'Bitcoin',
    symbol: 'btc',
    id: 'bitcoin',
    image: 'bitcoin_logo_url'
  },.....];

// length of arrWithSmallLength is less than 1000

console.log(arrWithSmallLength); // it prints the array normally

// example two

var arrWithBigLength = [  {
    name: 'Bitcoin',
    symbol: 'btc',
    id: 'bitcoin',
    image: 'bitcoin_logo_url'
  },.....];

// length of arrWithBigLength is more than than 8000

console.log(arrWithBigLength); // it prints undefined
```

> The arrWithBigLength rendered in VS Code in more than 78500 lines

**UPDATE**

find the data payload in this link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FIbMoLbtzRm7LqMaPZnE3EAL26sj4VOo/view

Comment: Can you show the code that loads the arrays?

Comment: There's no code loading it , just assign it to a variable and try to log it

Comment: When I say load I mean assign 8000+ elements to that array. How are you doing that? With a for loop? By manually setting `length = 8000`?

Comment: No , it's a ready data (hard coded)

Comment: As your sample does not contain the actual data which causes an issue, I tried the following: ```var arrWithBigLength = Array.from({length: 20000}).map((x,i) => ({name: 'Bitcoin-' + i,symbol: 'btc-' + i,id: 'bitcoin-' + i,image: 'bitcoin_logo_url_' + 1})); console.log(arrWithBigLength);```. This works perfectly with 20.000 records.
You getting ```undefined``` means there is something wrong with the actual fixed data you load into the variable.

Comment: @KevinVerstraete , here's the data (just try the value in data key) : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FIbMoLbtzRm7LqMaPZnE3EAL26sj4VOo/view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your json file, look for the value 'Staked yAxis'. After this entry you'll find

```
  }
]
[
  {
```

Here you repeat your data for a second time, causing a bad json definition. Remove the doubles after this line and your data works. Everything after line 39273 shouldn't be there (except for the closing `}`.